# ReactJS nothing in my nested iterator shows

Tags: reactjs

i am running a map function within a map function, but the JSX returned from my nested `map` doesnt return anything to the DOM. I have confirmed that the correct data is there.  Is there some sort of nuance with returning JSX from a nested loop?

```
{  chatList !== undefined && chatList.data[0][0].map((message, messageIndex) => {
                    // last message stuff
                    chatList.data[0][1].map((participant, participantIndex) => {
                        return <IonItem key={participantIndex}>
                            <IonAvatar slot="start">
                                {/*<img src={}/>*/}
                            </IonAvatar>
                            <IonLabel>
                                <h2>{participant.identity}</h2>

                                <p>{message.body}</p>
                                <p>{moment(message.dateCreated).format('MM/DD/YY HH:mm')}</p>
                            </IonLabel>
                        </IonItem>
                })})}
```

Comment: You’re not returning the inner map call. `return chatList.data[0][1].map…`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're missing the return statement in first map function:

```
{  chatList !== undefined && chatList.data[0][0].map((message, messageIndex) => {
     // added a return to the following line. Should work now
     return chatList.data[0][1].map((participant, participantIndex) => {
            return <IonItem key={participantIndex}>
                <IonAvatar slot="start">
                    {/*<img src={}/>*/}
                </IonAvatar>
                <IonLabel>
                    <h2>{participant.identity}</h2>

                    <p>{message.body}</p>
                    <p>{moment(message.dateCreated).format('MM/DD/YY HH:mm')}</p>
                </IonLabel>
            </IonItem>
                })})}
```